# Backing up proc & dev

Tags: backup

I've been having some trouble and managed to delete the entire /usr/share/mime directory. OK! reinstalled system, but thought backing up the root directory might be a good idea. From what I'm reading here

> [/proc kcore file is huge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170795/proc-kcore-file-is-huge/32105432#32105432)

and

> [A few /proc and /dev questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709298/a-few-proc-and-dev-questions)

I'm guessing that /dev & /proc will look after themselves - they only exist when the computer is "alive" (so it's not necessary to back them up)

Is this correct?

"Yes" or "No" is fine (I'm assuming "Yes")

but Thanks!

dmk

Answer (score 0):

proc - Yes, dev - generally Yes - use can check by

```
mount |grep " /dev "
```

Comment: @rastic Thanks for that. I'm getting   <br/>Bash - 4.2.37   : mount | grep " /dev "   <br/>
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=126206,mode=755)
I'm assuming that's OK. Actually, all I'm after, is a fully **rsynced** copy of root so I can repair any damn fool mistakes I make like the last one!  Thanks again - dmk

Comment: In your case "Yes" applies to dev too.